# Make RSpec print "context" descriptions before the descriptions in the "it" blocks

Tags: rspec, rspec2

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make rspec print the text from context blocks out before the text from the "it" blocks in failure messages? For example:

```
describe Array do
  context "when created with new" do
    it "is empty" do
      array = Array.new
      array << 1 # trigger a failure to demonstrate the message
      array.should be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Right now this would print "Array when created with new is empty" in the failure message.
That sounds a little awkward to me. Is there a way to make rspec say "Array is empty when created with new" instead? In my opinion that sounds a lot more natural. Just curious...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to have RSpec invert the order of the description strings, but if you use [the documentation formatter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format) your output will make a little more sense -- something like:

```
Array
  when created with new
    is empty
```

At least that way, the indentation clearly delimits the important phrases in the description.